# UITableView in Cocos2D ( can't select a row)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In my cocos2D(cocos2d 0.99.5 version) project i integrated a uiview as the following code

```
tView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-90,85,480,320)];  // ypo,xpos,width,height
    CGAffineTransform tr = tView.transform; // get current transform (portrait)
    tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, (M_PI / 2.0)); // rotate 90 degrees to go landscape
    tView.transform = tr; // set current transform (landscape)
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]  addSubview:tView];
```

and add a uitableview as a child to tView like this

```
tTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,480,320)

                                                      style:UITableViewStylePlain];

tTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

tTableView.delegate = self;

tTableView.dataSource = self;

[tTableView reloadData];

[self.pView addSubview:tTableView];
```

the UITableView added correctly but i can't select a row in tableview.it scroll well . how to solve the this problem. Please give some suggestion

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the Cocos2D version of UITableView, the CCTableView Suite, with the download page and examples [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/?s=cctableview). That would work much better than mixing a UIKit view with Cocos2D.